# Gitのローカルリポジトリからコミットログが消える原因

Tags: git

Gitを使ってソース管理をしています。
「pullをしたら、まだpushしていなかったコミットが全て消えた」という現象が、複数人の環境で発生しました。
彼らのローカルリポジトリからは、「pushしていなかったコミット」のコミットログすら、消えてしまったようです。

このような状況が起こる原因として、何が考えられるでしょうか？
なお、GitクライアントにはSourceTree（Windows版）を使用しています。

【追記】
teratailにもマルチポストしました。
https://teratail.com/questions/49918

Comment: pullする際にmergeする代わりにrebaseを選択し、競合の処理を間違ったとか……？（[参考](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/17902227/entire-commit-lost-in-sourcetree-after-pull-with-rebase-instead-of-merge)）
いずれにせよ消えたコミットは`git reflog`などで掘り起こせるかもしれませんが。

Comment: 単純にpullして消えるというのはやはり考えにくいので、何か操作ミスがあったか、消えたと勘違いしているのでは？というところです。remote側、pull前のローカル側（push前のコミットを含んでいるはず）、pull後のローカル側の履歴がどのようになっていたのかはわかりますか？またブランチはどのようになっていたのでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

SourceTreeは使っていないので実際の表示はわかりませんが、

```
$ git pull --rebase        # pullする際にmergeの代わりにrebaseする
```

で競合を起こし、競合をすべて

```
$ git rebase --skip        # 競合したコミットを適用せずスキップする
```

していくことでローカルのコミットがdanglingになる（消えたようにみえる）ことを確認しました。

誤ってこのような処理を実行したのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 残念ながら、そういう特殊な操作はしていらず、pullした途端に消えたようです。